# Copying specific column from one file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code to import data from one file to another.

The change I am looking for is to only bring in specific columns, for example column A, B and F.

I think its something to do with this code.

```
Sheets("Data").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Columns(2)
```

Main code:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Data!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.csv (*.csv),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updated based on answer below:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Data!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.csv (*.csv),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Copy wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to use the Excel txt assistant? Try to import the data as txt and choose your csv file.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego appreciate the suggestion but would really rather not use it

Comment: So could you upload one sample? For my understanding, your code is already working but it is importing all the data. Another suggestion: Use the macro recorder to import the data with the Excel txt assistant. The code you will get will help you.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego The code is so complicated when I recorded it that way I gave up. I just want to bring column A, B and F from the source across for example, not every column

Comment: You can do something like `Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A,E:E,F:F"))` or use `Union`.

Comment: @SJR would that go after the line With Sheet.UsedRange

Comment: How do you decide which columns to copy? or are they static columns that you need to copy?

Comment: @Zac just static ones yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I have over simplified this but if you just want to copy columns to a different sheet, try this:

**EDIT:** Added file selection option

```
Sub CopySpecificColumns()

    Dim oSourceWB As Workbook
    Dim oSourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oDestSheet As Worksheet: Set oDestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")         ' Set your destination sheet here
    Dim aColsToCopy, aDestColumns, sWBToOpen
    Dim iC As Long

    ' Get filename
    sWBToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Report Files (*.csv),", , "Please chose a Report to Parse", , False)

    ' Check that a file was selected
    If sWBToOpen = "False" Then Exit Sub

    ' Open workbook and set source sheet
    Set oSourceWB = Workbooks.Open(sWBToOpen)
    Set oSourceSheet = oDestWB.Sheets("Checklist")

    aColsToCopy = Array("B", "C", "E")      ' Set your cource columns here
    aDestColumns = Array("A", "B", "C")     ' Set your destination columns here

    ' Loop to copy columns
    For iC = LBound(aColsToCopy) To UBound(aColsToCopy)
        With oSourceSheet
            .Range(aColsToCopy(iC) & "1:" & aColsToCopy(iC) & .Range(aColsToCopy(iC) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy oDestSheet.Range(aDestColumns(iC) & "1")
        End With
    Next

    ' Close source workbook
    oSourceWB.Close False

    ' Clear objects
    Set oSourceSheet = Nothing
    Set oDestSheet = Nothing
    Set oSourceWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can add things like no screen updating is you want

Comment: Hi Zac, this is basically it, but I need to open a file browser and use that as the source, and move this to a different file

Comment: Added file selection

Answer (score 1):

Can't easily relay this in a comment.

Try changing the loop thus:

```
For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A,B:B,F:F")).Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End With
Next Sheet
```

Do you have the same number of rows of data in each column? If not, you will need to allow for this.

Comment: Thank you for this. Seems to work but in some cases cells will have blank data but I still want them copied as blank, will this cause issues?

Comment: Using `UsedRange` is not the most reliable - it will include blanks if they are "within" the used range, but not if they are after the last used row. Better to use `end(xlup)` formulation.

Comment: Is this not a simple way to do this? There is only one sheet of data on source, so I just need Copy A:A to Col A, Copy E:E to Col B for example?

Comment: You can't copy the whole column because when you come to the 2nd sheet you will be going off the bottom of the destination sheet.

Comment: There is only one sheet though of data if that makes a difference?

Comment: So no need for a loop. You could just use `.Range("A:A,B:B,F:F").Copy ...`

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry to be a pain but based on your suggestion I put some updated code in my question but it still doesnt work. This is designed to copy a single column across. Can you tell me why that doesnt work?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Are you copying cells with formulae? I thought you were trying to copy multiple columns.

Comment: Yes one column was just an example, really its 5